# Security Section is locked at parent level

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-config, iis-express

I know this is a quite common problem, but at my case I change all `applicationHost.config` but the problem still persist.

I am trying to local host my application via IIS Express, while the `web.config` set up some security settings. And while I try run the application in a browser, this famous error message is shown

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny")...

---

I know such problem can be fixed by changing the config of `applicationHost.config`'s `overrideModeDefault` and the `lockItem` attributes, here is the files I've changed:

- C:\Users\UserName\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config
- C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config
- ${solution path}\ .vs \config\applicationHost.config

I change them to 
`<section name="basicAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />` and also `<add name="BasicAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" />` (Similar for `AnonymousAuthentication` and `WindowsAuthentication`)

But then the error message still persists...

What am I missing, is there any other possible config files I need to change?